# Get Element by Tag inside ion-content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I manage to get the element of 'img' inside my page, but it detects all of the images including the images inside the ion-header. I only need to get the 'img' tag inside the ion-content or a div with ID.

I have tried using the Angular ViewChild to get the ID of the div. It detects the ID, but I'm not sure how to proceed next.

```
@ViewChild('newscontainer') newscont;

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {

  imgs[i].onclick = function(img) {
    console.log(img.srcElement.currentSrc)
  }
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div #newscontainer padding>
<img src="..." />
</div>
```

Content inside #newscontainer are parsed from a wordpress site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you want to find a specific element by tag, but only within a certain div/element (the one you defined a template variable `#` from).

If you want to use `@ViewChildren` you could try something like this:

```js
@ViewChild('newscontainer') newscont: ElementRef;
imgElmt: HTMLCollection;

ngAfterViewInit(){
 this.imgElmt = this.newscont.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('img');
 console.log(this.imgElmt);
}
```

From there you can get the attributes of that img element without issue. Although keep in mind that having multiple `img` tag in the div will give you a collection with multiple results. You should figure out what you want to do in this scenario.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic3-search-bar-sample-1dpuhj)

Comment: Thanks! We won't have more than 10 images in the scenario. So basically, I just want to get the image src to make it clickable for my other function. I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with HTMLCollection. How do I get the src path from the images?

Comment: Oh nevermind! Found a way to do it! Thanks @Jojofoulk

Answer (score 0):

You can access your image tag with onclick($event) every information about clicked div in this event parameter u can access from ts file and take action

```
<div #newscontainer padding>
 <img id="imgTag" (click)="imgClick($event)" src="..." />
</div>
```

ts file

```
imgClick(event){
  console.log(event.target.imgTag);
}
```

every information about your div into event variable. You can access your img with this sample of code

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The contents inside div#newscontainer are actually loaded from the wordpress site, so I cannot put the click event.

Comment: Fine. Now for this, we need a more efficient answer.